# Sync only accepted Facebook events in iOS calendar

Tags: ios, data-synchronization, calendar, facebook

If I activate the Facebook calendar sync on my iOS device all events are input in my calendar. Even those I denied. It's there a way to sync only those I accepted?

If it's not possible to do it with plain iOS, is there a way through third party tools? (I'm aware that they could log the calendar events)

Comment: Also asked here but not received answer: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/70608/only-sync-facebook-events-that-i-have-rsvped-yes-to-in-ios6

Comment: Yeah I saw that, but that was pretty outdated (iOS6). I hope something changed.

Comment: Use this http://eventcal.flown.io/

Comment: Why was Herman's new answer accepted when the same solution was [provided by another user last year](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/173523/37797)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Someone created a filter for that, that only puts through the accepted and maybe accepted Facebook events: http://eventcal.flown.io/

Works for Google calendar, and also all system calendars.

Comment: This is the same as [an answer provided by another user last year](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/173523/37797).

Answer (score 7):

You can use [Facebook Event Calendar](http://eventcal.flown.io/). Simple, efficient, clever, with options. Read every step carefully, and you'll be able to customize your calendar synchronisation and it works perfectly.

Comment: Freedom is down, so someone created this with same functionality http://eventcal.flown.io/

Answer (score 6):

This is currently not possible with the standard iOS calendar sync.

Signing in to Facebook on your iOS device and showing the events on your calendar will synchronise the entire calendar from the server on your device, including events to which you have not accepted. Calendar on iOS or OS X does not respect the response which you have given for the invitation as a method of deciding whether to show the event on your calendar.

This is detailed on Facebook's help center with a possible workaround:

- https://www.facebook.com/help/community/question/?id=607062449325928

> A better solution is not to use the FB calendar integration but instead subscribe yourself to your facebook events. You can do this by going to your events page on the full facebook site on a PC. Click on the cog in the top right hand corner and select export and then select upcoming events - copy the link from that and email it to yourself. Open the email on your iphone and click on the link. That will prompt you to subscribe to you FB events calendar which you should do. All your facebook events excluding declined events will now show in your iphone calendar.

The cog mentioned in Facebook's answer has been replaced by a link in the bottom right corner, "Upcoming Events".
[image: Upcoming Events]

You can provide feedback to Apple here:

- https://www.apple.com/feedback/iphone.html

Comment: I'm unable to find the aforementioned cog. Has it disappeared?

Comment: @AviSteiner It's been replaced by a rather discrete link! See the updated answer :)

Comment: The subscription link from the cog includes all events, not only accepted unfortunately.